# How to solve 'log2FoldChange is not numeric error' on R package EnhancedVolcano?

Tags: r

I'm new to R and I'm trying to run R package EnhancedVolcano for generating a plot. My input csv file is a list of differentially expressed genes from DESeq2. The first column contains gene names that do not occur uniquely and so as to avoid `duplicate rownames error`, I decided to make.unique by adding .1 etc to the column 1 names as below. However, I keep getting the error `log2FoldChange is not numeric!`" for the below code

```
library(EnhancedVolcano)
results <- read.table("Volcano_DEGlist_Age12_vs_Age0.csv", sep=',', header=T, fill=T)
row.names(results) <- make.unique(results[,1])
results[,1] <- NULL
toptable <- as.data.frame(results)
pdf("Volcano_plot.pdf", width=10, height=8)
EnhancedVolcano(toptable,lab=rownames(toptable),x="log2FoldChange",y="padj")
dev.off()
```

If I do `head(results)`, it looks like the below

```
                          product         baseMean   log2FoldChange
myl3         Myosin light chain 3 6849.06763363829 4.79154418899226
acylcoa               desaturase 21579.7092004583 5.85468152540418
clec3b                Tetranectin  1302.8225789416 6.87376512160426
pxn1     Pentraxin fusion protein 7602.05568921881 7.13359339560787
prva            Parvalbumin alpha 479358.794450277 6.30662126922836
s10i                   Ictacalcin 15403.2762003105 3.30738389209604
                     lfcSE             stat        pvalue          padj
myl3     0.115445384476954 41.5048571296392  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
acylcoa  0.15423331916501 37.9599009935097  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
clec3b   0.163338998880989 42.0828165269495  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
pxn1     0.172092195486355 41.4521610085071  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
prva     0.169687176699443 37.1661630059348 2.403555e-302 1.351904e-298
s10i     0.091992500797751 35.9527555334912 4.583656e-283 2.148436e-279
```

`str(results)` gives me the below

```
str(results)'data.frame':   3512 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ product       : chr  "Myosin light chain 3" "desaturase" "Tetranectin" "Pentraxin fusion protein" ...
 $ baseMean      : chr  "6849.06763363829" "21579.7092004583" "1302.8225789416" "7602.05568921881" ...
 $ log2FoldChange: chr  "4.79154418899226" "5.85468152540418" "6.87376512160426" "7.13359339560787" ...
 $ lfcSE         : chr  "0.115445384476954" "0.15423331916501" "0.163338998880989" "0.172092195486355" ...
 $ stat          : chr  "41.5048571296392" "37.9599009935097" "42.0828165269495" "41.4521610085071" ...
 $ pvalue        : num  0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 2.4e-302 ...
 $ padj          : num  0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 1.35e-298 ...
```

I tried setting `results$log2FoldChange <- as.numeric(results$log2FoldChange)` but the error persists. Alternatively, is there a way to load directly the csv containing the non-unique gene names without resorting to `make.unique`? Any help to fix this would be very much appreciated

Comment: Take a look at `results$log2FoldChange`. Perhaps there are empty cells `""` or similar values that force `log2FoldChange` to be a character vector.

Comment: Many thanks for your prompt response@Martin Gal I did check out as yo suggested and there does seem to be spaces. Any way to clean up?

Comment: I have made available my input csv file [link] (https://www.dropbox.com/s/ioy73maam27r92d/Volcano_DEGlist_Age12_vs_Age0.csv?dl=0) on Dropbox

Comment: Have a look at `results["nt5e","log2FoldChange"]`, it clearly can't be numeric

Comment: Thanks@BastienDucreux but when I do `grep "nt5e" Volcano_DEGlist_Age12_vs_Age0.csv` it indeed returns a numeric value in column 4 i.e., the log2FoldChange column
nt5e,5'-nucleotidase,301.666924941805,2.42013919007082,0.203921791233347,11.8679773036196,1.73614510870745E-32,7.60523502993453E-31

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a potential solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)
#BiocManager::install("EnhancedVolcano")
library(EnhancedVolcano)
#> Loading required package: ggrepel
#> Registered S3 methods overwritten by 'ggalt':
#>   method                  from   
#>   grid.draw.absoluteGrob  ggplot2
#>   grobHeight.absoluteGrob ggplot2
#>   grobWidth.absoluteGrob  ggplot2
#>   grobX.absoluteGrob      ggplot2
#>   grobY.absoluteGrob      ggplot2

df <- read_csv("~/Downloads/Volcano_DEGlist_Age12_vs_Age0.csv")
#> New names:
#> * `` -> ...1
#> Rows: 5033 Columns: 8
#> ── Column specification ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> Delimiter: ","
#> chr (2): ...1, product
#> dbl (6): baseMean, log2FoldChange, lfcSE, stat, pvalue, padj
#> 
#> ℹ Use `spec()` to retrieve the full column specification for this data.
#> ℹ Specify the column types or set `show_col_types = FALSE` to quiet this message.

# One of the fields was read into R without a column name
# and it was named by the read_csv function as "...1"
# i.e. "#> * `` -> ...1"
# You can either edit your csv to include a name for that column
# or rename it to something like 'gene_name': 
df$gene_name <- df$...1

# You don't necessarily need to use the rownames as labels
# if you have duplicate transcript names because of
# isoforms / splicing / whatever, I think having duplicates
# or a few 'unknown's on the plot is fine, e.g.
EnhancedVolcano(df, lab = df$gene_name,
                x = 'log2FoldChange',
                y = 'pvalue')
#> Warning: One or more p-values is 0. Converting to 10^-1 * current lowest non-
#> zero p-value...
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-09-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much for your wonderful solution @jared_mamrot; you're a life saver! I noticed that you remarked about duplicate transcript names. I actually ran conventional DESeq2 to look at differentially expressed genes (and not transcripts or isoforms). I have unique gene ids in the counts file but gene id numbers aren't informative to put on a volcano plot and hence I replaced those unique gene ids with their respective gene names. I suppose it is OK to assume that some of the unique gene ids can actually share identical gene names? Aren't multiple copies of the same genes possible?

Comment: Also, the gtf reference has not got any ENSEMBL gene ids on it (it just has got gene id numbers from running maker-augustus pipeline-not run by me though!) I 'm new to this sort of analysis and I just wanna be sure that I'm committing any major errors here. Thanks a ton again!

Comment: Sorry, I meant "NOT" committing any major errors

Comment: Yes - to my understanding, that is correct. I don't think you're making any major errors, but if you want to 'ask the experts' the best place is https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/. Also, you'll find them a lot more helpful with 'please help me understand this'-type questions, whereas stackoverflow is geared towards professional programmers with programming-related questions and there is a greater expectation that you 'figure out your problem yourself'. Also, https://www.biostars.org/ used to be great for this type of question, but I haven't been on there in years so I don't know now

Comment: Many thanks again @jared_mamrot for sharing your insights & suggestions- much appreciated! I'll check out bioinformatics.stackexchange.com

Comment: @jared_mamrot Thank you for the solution how do i label let say top 10 gene both up and down ?

Comment: Follow the instructions at https://github.com/kevinblighe/EnhancedVolcano#only-label-key-variables @kcm, or perhaps you could use something like `df$gene_name <- ifelse(df$pvalue %in% head(sort(df$pvalue), n = 10) | df$pvalue %in% tail(sort(df$pvalue), n = 10), df$gene_name, "")`? If you can't figure it out, post a new question (including a minimal reproducible example; re https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Good luck!

Comment: @jared_mamrot i fixed it with your suggestion